# member visibility and 'this' scope in javascript objects

Tags: c#, javascript

I still haven't quite wrapped my head around object definitions and the `this` scope in javascript. I think the (c#ish) pseudocode below sums it up quite nicely.

How can I define a piece of javascript code that creates an object that has all of the following properties:

1. private members that are only visible inside the methods of the object
2. public members that are also visible outside the object
3. a (parametrized) constructor that is executed when the object is instantiated and initializes members
4. register callback inside the object that points to a method of the object itself
5. when the callback is executed inside the method (`PrivateMethod`) it is possible to access all members of the object instance, preferably using the `this` pointer

.

```
class MyObjectDefinition
{
    public int publicField = 0;
    private int privateField;

    public MyObjectDefinition(int parameter)
    {
        this.privateField = parameter;   
        SomethingThatWantsA.CallBack(this.PrivateMethod);
    }

    public void PublicMethod()
    {
        this.privateField--;
        this.publicField--;
    }

    private void PrivateMethod()
    {
        this.privateField++;
        this.publicField++;
    }
}

var instance = new MyObjectDefinition();
```

Comment: If you real question is "how to use proper `this` in `PrivateMethod` when it used as callback" than check out [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) that solves exactly this problem.

Comment: I am looking for a concise and clean way to write the above sample in javascript. I understand now that I can using `bind` to redirect `this` to a specific instance. But what about the visibility and the constructor?

Comment: Also, is there any significant difference, advantage ore disadvantage in using the `.prototype` notation to declare public members?

Comment: `.prototype` is generally better and importation to use if you plan to use many instances of that type or "deriving" classes.

Comment: Since this is a wiki now, maybe we should add another answer with a `.prototype` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- public => `this.`
- private => local variable/function inside constructor
- callback with correct `this` - either use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or save `this` in local variable (`me` or `that` are traditional names).

Something similar to following:

```
function MyObjectDefinition()
{
    this.publicField = 0;
    var that = this;
    var privateField;

    this.MyObjectDefinition = function(parameter)
    {
        privateField = parameter;   
        SomethingThatWantsA.CallBack(PrivateMethod);
    }

    this.PublicMethod = function()
    {
        privateField--;
        // or that.publicField--; if you are paranoid/like consistency
        this.publicField--; 
    }

    function PrivateMethod()
    {
        privateField++;
        that.publicField++;
    }
}

var instance = new MyObjectDefinition();
```

Comment: `+1` - Great explanation.  Figuring out where `this` points to is one of the trickiest parts of JavaScript to understand, especially if you come from an object-oriented programming background.

Comment: Just one side note: The `int` in the `parameter` declaration is not valid javascript, it must be deleled. 
Also, I think this `this.MyObjectDefinition = function(parameter) {...}` is not a real constructor the user of my "class" needs to explicitly call `var instance = new MyObjectDefinition(); instance.MyObjectDefinition(42);` to correctly initialize the object. Whereas in c# you cannot even instantiate the object without specifying a parameter for the constructor.

Comment: @bitbonk, fixed `int` in argument. JavaScript is not C# - everything is more or less optional in JavaScript compared to C#/Java (i.e. arguments are optional - but you can verify if arguments are passed in with `arguments.length` check). You can use Script# to write JavaScript code in C#. I'd recommend to read [JavaScript the good parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742) to get better insight in JavaScript.

Comment: There must be something to this book, I have seen it being recommended a lot of times now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [**link**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/video/18312985) to video in which Doug Hendricks from Sencha explaines JavaScript variable scope and common "execution context" (scope) in depht.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed [Alexei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16614603/4227) a little bit to get rid of the issue I see with the constructor.

```
function MyObjectDefinition(parameter)
{
    this.publicField = 0;
    var that = this;
    var privateField;

    this.PublicMethod = function()
    {
        privateField--;
        this.publicField--;
    }

    if(parameter !== undefined)
    {
        privateField = parameter;
        SomethingThatWantsACallBack(PrivateMethod);
        SomethingThatWantsACallBack(this.PublicMethod);
    }

    function PrivateMethod()
    {
        privateField++;  
        that.publicField++;
    }
}
```

What I still don't like about this solution is that I can't have all the constructor logic at the top of the `class`. Unlike `PrivateMethod` I have to define the `PublicMethod` before I can use it.